# Condição Para Rodar Função __Construct

Tags: php, laravel

Criei uma função `__construct` no **Controller.php** do Laravel 5.

E essa função obviamente está rodando inclusive na tela de Login, no **Auth**.

Tem alguma forma de eu colocar como condição, rodar a função dentro do `__construct` apenas quando o usuário estiver logado ?

Eu sei uma forma de fazer, no começo da função eu coloco:

```
if(Auth::check())
    # Roda Função
```

Mas tem outra maneira ? Dessa forma acima toda vez ele vai fazer a verificação.

### `__construct`

```
public function __construct(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        # Monta Menu e Sub Menu
        $menu       = Menu::orderBy('posicao')->get();

        $arrMenu    = array();

        foreach($menu as $itemMenu){
            $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['titulo']   = $itemMenu->titulo;
            $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['link']     = $itemMenu->link;
            $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['icon']     = $itemMenu->icon;
            $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['slug']     = $itemMenu->slug;

            $submenu            = Submenu::whereIdMenu($itemMenu->id)->orderBy('posicao')->get();

            foreach($submenu as $itemSubMenu){
                $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['submenu'][$itemSubMenu->titulo]['titulo']  = $itemSubMenu->titulo;
                $arrMenu[$itemMenu->titulo]['submenu'][$itemSubMenu->titulo]['link']    = $itemSubMenu->link;
            }
        }

        # Total de Chamados Agrupado por Status no Menu
        if(Auth::user()->id_role == 1){
            $chamados = DB::table('chamados')
                        ->rightJoin('status', 'status.id', '=', 'chamados.id_status')
                        ->select(DB::raw('count(chamados.id) as total, status, status.id as id_status'))
                        ->orderBy('status.id')
                        ->groupBy('status')
                        ->get();
        }
        else{
            $chamados = DB::table('chamados')
                        ->select(DB::raw('count(chamados.id) as total, status, status.id as id_status'))
                        ->orderBy('status.id')
                        ->groupBy('status')
                        ->rightJoin('status', function($join){
                            $join->on('status.id', '=', 'chamados.id_status')
                                 ->where('id_departamento', '=', Auth::user()->id_departamento)
                                 ->where('id_user', '=', Auth::id())
                                 ->orWhere('id_user', '=', NULL);
                        })
                        ->get();
        }

        $totalFinal = 0;

        foreach ($chamados as $key => $value){
            $totalChamado[$value->id_status] = $value->total;
            $totalFinal                     += $value->total;
        }

        # Coloca em Array o Menu e o Total de Chamados para Colocar no Share
        $arrShare = array(
            'menu'      => $arrMenu,
            'chamados'  => $totalChamado,
            'total'     => $totalFinal
        );

        view()->share('arrShare', $arrShare);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem outro jeito, que eu saiba. Se você quiser verificar que um usuário está logado ou não, sempre terá que fazer a verificação a cada requisição feita pelo usuário.

Nesse caso, eu não usaria o método `__construct`, mas sim os [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsAuthMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Faço a minha mágica aqui
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Para configurar isso, você tem que alterar o `AppKernel`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
]
```

No arquivo de `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
```

Comment: Eu uso **Middleware** para este fim. O problema mesmo é que no `__construct` fiz uma função que cria um MENU. E como o MENU vai em todas as páginas criei no **Controller.php**. Vou postar.

Comment: Não, não, @TaoPaiPai. Nesse caso não faça assim! Controller é para requisições. `View` é outra camada. Use o `View::share` para gerar esse menu.  Assim você compartilhará uma variável (ou mais) para todas as views.

Comment: Use o `BeforeMiddleWare` para isso

Comment: Está meio confuso ainda... vou criar um `BeforeMiddleware`. Coloco a função que cria o MENU dentro desta ? Depois registro no `AppKernel` e depois coloco na Route ?

Comment: É que você editou a questão depois. Na verdade, você vai usar somente o `BeforeMiddleWare`. Lá você vai registrar a variável em `View::share`.

Comment: Mas qual a sequência de como fazer isso ? É como eu disse no comentário acima ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai, não entendi a questão da "sequência". Você faz as declarações. É o Laravel que vai colocar primeiro o middleware em execução, depois a redenrização.

Comment: Vou te falar o que fiz sequencialmente: `php artisan make:middleware BeforeMiddleware`. Depois peguei a função que estava no **Controller.php** e coloquei dentro do `handle` do arquivo **BeforeMiddleware.php**. Registrei no **Kernel**. Eu tenho que colocar na route agora ?

Comment: Consegui, mano. Você não sabe de nada. Obrigado!